# How to avoid rerendering all list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On every click react rerender every item. How to avoid it? I want react to only render items that have changed. I tried using react memo and usecallback but it didn't help. I can't understand what is the reason. What are the ways to solve this problem? Thank you.

**App.ts**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

const items = [
  { id: 1, text: "items1" },
  { id: 2, text: "items2" },
  { id: 3, text: "items3" },
  { id: 4, text: "items4" },
  { id: 5, text: "items5" },
  { id: 6, text: "items6" },
  { id: 7, text: "items7" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(1);
  const onClick = (newActiveIndex: number) => {
    setActiveIndex(newActiveIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map(({ id, text }) => (
        <ListItem
          key={id}
          id={id}
          text={text}
          activeId={activeIndex}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Item.ts**

```
import React from "react";

interface ListItemProps {
  id: number;
  activeId: number;
  text: string;
  onClick: (newActiveIndex: number) => void;
}

const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = ({ id, activeId, text, onClick }) => {
  const isActive = activeId === id;
  const style = {
    marginRight: "42px",
    marginTop: "24px",
    color: isActive ? "green" : "red"
  };
  console.log(`update id: ${id}`);

  return (
    <div>
      <span style={style}>id: {id}</span>
      <span style={style}>is active: {isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}</span>
      <span style={style}>text: {text}</span>
      <button onClick={() => onClick(id)}>setActive</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

Comment: Your list items must have itself state create your list by useState with their content as default content. You should see desired behavior

Comment: activeId is a prop of each list item, so whenever it changes they all get re-rendered.  What if you passed a true/false isActive prop instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`activeIndex` changes with each click, so all of the components have new prop values and will need to re-render.

Instead of passing the `activeIndex` to every component every time:

```
const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = ({ id, activeId, text, onClick }) => {
  const isActive = activeId === id;
```

Pass an `isActive` to each component:

```
const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = ({ id, isActive, text, onClick }) => {
```

Effectively moving the calculation of the `bool` from the component to the consuming code:

```
<ListItem
  key={id}
  id={id}
  text={text}
  isActive={activeIndex === id}
  onClick={onClick}
/>
```

Then memoization (coupled with `useCallback` for the `onClick` handler) should work because most components (the ones which aren't changing their "active" state) won't receive new props and won't need to re-render.

Comment: OP could do `onClick={setActiveIndex}` and would not need `useCallback`, since `setActiveIndex` is already memoized and `onClick` is just forwarding the call.

Answer (score 2):

Even with memoization it won't work, because your `onClick` function changes your components state, and your children components depend on `activeIndex` value, so every time you click you change the components state, and when state changes, the component re-renders itself and it's children, if your children didn't depend on your state, they wouldn't re-render (if you use memoization).

Answer (score 0):

Plus to David's answer i would return ListItem in React.memo `React.memo(ListItem)`